# nth Child Grid Selection

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm looking to build the following grid structure like the supporting image below, so that it carries on with the same pattern, but I'm unsure on what nth child rule I should be using, I've tried quite a few to no avail.

[image]

My Current code is

```
.category:nth-child(5n+1)
{
  width:48%;
  max-width: 48%;
}
```

But unfortunately, this is leaving a row of 4 between my desired effect.

Comment: Do you have any code so far? It would be helpful to see where exactly you're stuck or if you could provide more specific instructions as to browser support requirements, responsiveness, flexibility, behavior.

Comment: I've added the current code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume these items are floating and that you want to be able to add infinitely many and keep the same pattern.

In this case I would use two selectors, because you need to select the first and the last items out of every block of six.

```
.category:nth-child(6n), .category:nth-child(6n-5) {
    max-width: 48%;
    width: 48%;
}
```